# Cannot find module "qs"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working to setup node on a Windows pc. I'm new to this so figuring this out has been time consuming. The instructions I received were to do "npm install" and then "node index.js".

This is the error I received:

> ```
> Error: Cannot find module 'qs'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
>     at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>     at Object.<anonymous>(C:\Users\WLL\Desktop\Coding\WebDev_Code_Test\api\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\query.js:16:10)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
> ```

Any ideas where to start?

Comment: Show your `package.json` please

Comment: {
  "name": "site-code",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "API",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "chance": "^1.0.4",
    "json-server": "^0.8.18",
    "qs": "^6.4.0",       
  }
}

Comment: Did you do `npm install` in the same folder as the `package.json` file? Also, next time just post the contents of the `package.json` in the original post itself, by editing it.

Answer (score 4):

`npm install --save qs`

and then run perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command

`rm -rf node_modules
 npm i`